# Ubuntu version for browsing pages on low-end netbook

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, browser

I have AAO110 (512ram, atom 270N)
What is best version of Ubuntu, if i need just web? UNR 10.04 was almost fine, but i wonder if there are better options now.

browser, blue-tooth, WiFi, long battery, no extra elements on screen (e.g. not like in Unity) while browser opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems) might help you.

Comment: Thank you. Finally I stick with 10.04 and make some adjustments from provided link. For me it is best solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

I tested Ubuntu 10.10 on old PCs and Laptops. Including MINI ones. You can install the 10.10 netbook and even the desktop one in that PC with no problem via the Live USB. Of course if you install the desktop it will all look pretty small hehe. but it works great. Loads fast, no problems whatsoever with any of my clients.

With this said, you can test the Firefox 3.6 that comes with ubuntu 10.10 or download the chrome version for it. Both cases work good. Even on a 512mb machine.